# Stack Corruption While Compiling with LTCG

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization

I'm getting this weird crash that only happens when it's enabled. I'm fairly sure it's some sort of stack corruption, but the details of the crash are very strange.

```
void CMover::UpdateParts(int nSex, int nSkinSet, int nFace, int nHairMesh, int nHeadMesh,
PEQUIP_INFO pEquipInfo, CModelObject* pModel, ItemContainer* pEquipment, BOOL bIfParts,
CMover* pMover)
{
    if (pModel == nullptr) // returns false, aka in runtime, the pModel pointer isn't being evaluated to 0
    {
        MooLog::Write("CMover::UpdateParts : pModel is nullptr");
        return;
    }

    if (bIfParts)
    {
        // if I uncomment the following line, it won't crash for some reason
        //MooLog::Write("CMover::UpdateParts : pModel is %08X", 3);

        // Crashes on the following line accessing invalid memory(0x000000C0, which is the offset of m_nPartsIdx)
        // It's strange that pModel is evaluating to zero here, considering it was just checked a few lines prior.
        pModel->m_nPartsIdx = 0; 
    }
...
}
```

Assume singlethreaded app, seeing as no other threads would be writing at the time of this crash. Compiling with VC11 x86.

Comment: You probably have some undefined behaviour somewhere. It could be anywhere. Try some static analysis tools.

Comment: I don't know if I can help, but I'm curious what assembly is generated for the snippet both with and without LTCG. I agree with @NeilKirk that undefined behavior is probably the culprit. I'm imagining that here the undefined behavior manifests in the optimizer not noticing that the register (or stack location) holding pModel is in use. so it gets overwritten.